# help with event click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm developing a html with this structure

```
div id="menuContainer">
    <div class = "menu ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <label class="formatText">Cliente</label><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e menuIcon" style="float: right"></span>
            <div class = "subMenu ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                <ul class="options">
                    <li>
                        <label class="formatText">Ver Cliente</label><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" style="float: right"></span>
                            <div class = "subMenuRight ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                                <ul class="options">
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="formatText">Por Nombre</label><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" style="float: right"></span>
                                            <div class = "subMenuRight ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                                                <ul class="options">
                                                    <li><label class="formatText">sub sub menu</label></li>
                                                    <li><label class="formatText">prueba</label></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="formatText">Por Campana</label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="formatText">Reportes para Cliente</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

notice that the principal div have class called `menu`, in the inside there are a some divs that with a classes called `subMenu` and `subMenuRight`, my problem it's that i want associate a event click to the father and other behavior to the divs children i tried like this

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    alert('click in the father');
});
$(".subMenu li").click(function () {
    alert('click in the first child');
});
$(".subMenuRight li").click(function () {
    alert('click in the second child');
});
```

The problem with this code it's that div father contains the divs children all the event handler are triggered. So my question is How can I modify the selector or validate the in the event handler for to only fire the exactly element that is clicked??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `event.stopPropagation()` for all the click handlers e.g.

```
$(".menu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    alert('click in the father');
});
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yFFGS/**

Comment: there's a problem when you clicked some element of the class `sunMenuright`

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look [here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) for an outline of different options.

`false` basically calls `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` which will be treated on below.

`preventDefault` stops the default behavior of the event -- in this case, it could stop an anchor from firing. You won't be terribly concerned with this behavior in your current example as you aren't actually

`event.stopPropagation` Prevents parent nodes from "hearing" the event. It will, however, allow anchor tags to continue working. Unless you want a parent of `.menu` to listen to the event, this will do what you are looking for. ***It is technically the most correct in this case***.

`event.stopImmediatePropagation` calls stopPropagation and then makes sure that all listeners which have been added after the listener which calls that event will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop event bubling just return false from the handler.

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    alert('click in the father');
    return false;
});
$(".subMenu li").click(function () {
    alert('click in the first child');
    return false;
});
$(".subMenuRight li").click(function () {
    alert('click in the second child');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menuContainer')
    .delegate('.menu', 'click', function() {
        alert(1);
        return false;
    })
    .delegate('.subMenu li', 'click', function() {
        alert(2);
        return false;
    })
    .delegate('.subMenuRight li', 'click', function() {
        alert(3);
        return false; // this stops triggering events on parent els
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the html code, there are two `li`'s each for `subMenu` and `subMenuRight`. Maybe you should use the `:first` selector in each case:

```
$(".subMenu li:first").click(function () {
    alert('click in the first child');
});
$(".subMenuRight li:first").click(function () {
    alert('click in the second child');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `.bind()` instead you can set the preventBubble variable to false to prevent clicks bubbling up to parent elements (http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$(".menu").bind('click', function () {
    alert('click in the father');
}, false);
$(".subMenu li").bind('click', function () {
    alert('click in the first child');
}, false);
$(".subMenuRight li").bind('click', function () {
    alert('click in the second child');
}, false);
```